# Can I prevent a folder of a certain name being created?

Tags: linux, directory, directory-structure

I'm working on a LAMP web app and there is a scheduled process somewhere which keeps creating a folder called `shop` in the root of the site. Every time this appears it causes conflicts with rewrite rules in the app, not good.

Until I find the offending script, is there a way to prevent any folder called `shop` being created in the root? I know that I can change the permissions on a folder to prevent it's contents being changed, but I have not found a way to prevent a folder of a certain name being created.

Comment: To find out what's doing the creating, you can [enable auditing](https://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't, given the user creating the directory has sufficient permission to write on the parent directory.

You can instead leverage the `inotify` family of system calls provided by the Linux kernel, to watch for the creation (and optionally `mv`-ing) of directory `shop` in the given directory, if created (or optionally `mv`-ed), `rm` the directory.

The userspace program you need in this case is `inotifywait` (comes with `inotify-tools`, install it first if needed).

---

Assuming the directory `shop` would be residing in `/foo/bar` directory, let's set a monitoring for `/foo/bar/shop` creation, and `rm` instantly if created:

```
inotifywait -qme create /foo/bar | \
             awk '/,ISDIR shop$/ { system("rm -r -- /foo/bar/shop") }'
```

- `inotifywait -qme create /foo/bar` watches `/foo/bar` directory for any file/directory that might be created i.e. watch for any `create` event
- If created, `awk '/,ISDIR shop$/ { system("rm -r -- /foo/bar/shop") }'` checks if the file happens to be a directory and the name is `shop` (`/,ISDIR shop$/`), if so `rm` the directory (`system("rm -r -- /foo/bar/shop")`)

You need to run the command as a user that has write permission on directory `/foo/bar` for removal of `shop` from the directory.

---

If you want to monitor `mv`-ing operations too, add watch for `moved_to` event too:

```
inotifywait -qme create,moved_to /foo/bar | \
             awk '/,ISDIR shop$/ { system("rm -r -- /foo/bar/shop") }'
```

---

Just to note, if you are looking for a file, not directory, named `shop`:

```
inotifywait -qme create /foo/bar | \
                 awk '$NF == "shop" { system("rm -- /foo/bar/shop") }'

inotifywait -qme create,moved_to /foo/bar | \
                 awk '$NF == "shop" { system("rm -- /foo/bar/shop") }'
```

Comment: Moreover if you're using `inotifywait` to do this it's also possible that the trigger might also be able to catch the process with `ps -ef`

Answer (score 30):

To answer literally based on the question of preventing a **folder** of a certain name to be created.

`touch shop`

You can't create a directory if a file with a identical name existing

`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘shop’: File exists`

Comment: This * may not* be enough. mkdir may not do it, but it can be done. It's a good first try though.

Comment: On Linux systems, use `chattr +i shop` to make it immutable. Until the immutable flag is removed, it can't even be renamed/deleted.

Comment: This is a smart little trick, not quite right for my situation but a clever idea for certain circumstances 

Comment: @R.. interesting. I expected `rename(2)` to still work, since name is not a part of inode, but it doesn't. Quick internet search doesn't reveal why. Any hints?

Comment: @domen: Because that's part of the purpose of the "immutable" attribute. I suspect it takes nontrivial extra work at the implementation level to prevent `rename` from working.

Answer (score 5):

What about hijacking `mkdir` syscall with `LD_PRELOAD`...?

```
$ ls
test.c
$ cat test.c 
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int (*orig_mkdir_func_type)(const char *path, mode_t mode);

int mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode) {
    if(!strcmp(path, "shop")) return 1;

    orig_mkdir_func_type orig_func;
    orig_func = (orig_mkdir_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "mkdir");
    return orig_func(path, mode);
}
$ gcc -shared -fPIC test.c -o test.so
$ LD_PRELOAD='./test.so' mkdir test
$ LD_PRELOAD='./test.so' mkdir shop
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘shop’: No such file or directory
$ ls
test  test.c  test.so
```

Note that inside this handler you can log PID of process that want to create this directory instead:

```
$ cat test.c 
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int (*orig_mkdir_func_type)(const char *path, mode_t mode);

int mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode) {
    if(!strcmp(path, "shop")) {
        FILE* fp = fopen("/tmp/log.txt", "w");
        fprintf(fp, "PID of evil script: %d\n", (int)getpid());
        fclose(fp);
    }

    orig_mkdir_func_type orig_func;
    orig_func = (orig_mkdir_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "mkdir");
    return orig_func(path, mode);
}
$ gcc -shared -fPIC test.c -o test.so
$ LD_PRELOAD='./test.so' mkdir shop
$ cat /tmp/log.txt 
PID of evil script: 8706
```

You need to place this in `~/.bashrc` of root (or whoever is running your app) to ensure this will be used:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/test.so
```

Comment: this shouldn't have a downvote, it's a solution and a good one

Comment: It's using a suitcase nuke to open a tin of beans. But hey at least they'll be cooked...

Comment: @cat: I disagree. `LD_PRELOAD` hacks like this are basically always wrong, and unless you know what you're doing, they can **badly** break the program you load them into by breaking properties like the async-signal-safety of the function you're replacing.

Comment: @R.. Oh, okay, I guess you have a point. However, the program in the OP is implicitly malicious so I think it's okay in this case, right?

Comment: Also, I think `fopen` should have `"a"` instead of `"w"`,  so it can preserve previous logs

Comment: @cat: The `LD_PRELOAD` is going to be inherited by any child processes unless the environment is cleared before exec. So it affects a lot more than just the intended "malicious" target.

Comment: @R.. That's fair enough, this should perhaps be marked ***unsafe*** then :)

Comment: This also won't work if bad code calls the syscall directly, not through libc. Or if the bad code is statically linked.

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD` is also trivial for a user to circumvent - it's an environment variable in the address space of a process *that the user owns*.

Answer (score 4):

(Would have commented on Miati's answer but can't remember my old account and don't have enough reputation on this new one...)

You can block creation by creating a file and then changing the file attributes.

```
$ sudo touch shop
$ sudo chattr +i shop
```

Then any attempt to do anything with that file will be blocked -- even if the user becomes root.

```
$ rm shop
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘shop’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘shop’: Operation not permitted
$ sudo rm shop
rm: cannot remove ‘shop’: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: If you know the name / email address of your old account, you can request an account merge from the [contact form linked at the bottom of every page](//unix.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: Also, why not tell us how this is related to the other answer, rather than why you decided to post?

Answer (score 4):

Create a symlink pointing to a non-existing location inside a non-existing directory. This has some fun implications:

```
$ ln -s non-existent/foobar foo
$ ls -ln
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000 19 Okt  4 17:17 foo -> non-existent/foobar
$ mkdir foo
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘foo’: File exists
$ cat foo
cat: foo: No such file or directory
$ echo foo > foo
zsh: no such file or directory: foo
```

1. mkdir, link and others will fail with `EEXIST` (File exists).
2. Attempting to open the path for reading, writing or appending will fail with `ENOENT` (No such file or directory)
3. Using stat(2) (not lstat(2) or stat(1)) on the location also fails with `ENOENT`. lstat will of course return the information about the symlink.

This has two advantages over some of the other solutions proposed here: (a) you don’t need a service running which tracks the creation of the directory and (b) the name appears to be nonexisting to most commands.

You will have to give it a shot, but I suspect that whatever rewrite rules you have, they don’t use lstat or other non-dereferencing commands, making them fail.