# How can I overwrite a file and run a command if the file actually changes?

Tags: files, configuration, services

Essentially I want to run a command and capture its output to a file:

```
some_cmd > /etc/myservice.conf
```

and I want to run a different command only if that results in the contents changing:

```
systemctl myservice reload
```

It should run with literally any difference:

- Same data, different order
- File doesn't yet exist or is empty
- Extra newline added at end
- New file is empty

I was thinking something similar to `tee`, for example:

```
echo "value=1" | overwritediff /etc/myservice.conf && systemctl myservice reload
```

I could do this with temp files and `diff`, just wondering if there's a cleaner way. Really it's fine if the answer is "no, write a script".

---

This is what I'll do otherwise:

```
some_cmd > /tmp/myservice.conf

diff /etc/myservice.conf /tmp/myservice.conf || (
  mv /tmp/myservice.conf /etc/myservice.conf && systemctl myservice reload
)
```

Comment: Maybe something like this using inotify? https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Comment: If the file changes at all, or if the new value appears in the file?

Comment: What do you mean by "effective contents "? Could there be repeated name/value pairs that change the file but not the "effect"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I prevent a folder of a certain name being created?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/can-i-prevent-a-folder-of-a-certain-name-being-created)

Comment: @JeffSchaller All I meant was "different" -- if you overwrite a file its contents "change" even if you overwrite with the same data (and the file has the same checksum before and after).

Comment: I added more detail and an alternate example, hopefully that's enough to reopen. I think it's perfectly acceptable if the answer is literally "no, there's no better way" because there's no where else I can find that says that (which would have saved me asking this in the first place).

Comment: @gregmac "if you overwrite a file its contents "change" even if you overwrite with the same data (and the file has the same checksum before and after)" - your `diff` solution wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Can I say: you need execute command, if the file was touched? And does not matter, was file content changed or not. Right? Because, if the " file has the same checksum before and after", content does not changed, but access and modification times were changed.

Comment: @MiniMax No I was specifically looking for changed, not just touched. The idea is run this tool to generate a config file (every few minutes), then only tell the service to actually reload when necessary. The file may only actually change a couple times a day. It's a fairly common pattern I've run into a few times, I was just curious if there was a common way (aside from dealing with temp files and a script) to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple shell script using [sha1sum](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sha1sum)?

```
#!/bin/bash

VALUE=$1
FILE=$2

SUM1=$(sha1sum $FILE)
echo "value=$VALUE" > $FILE
SUM2=$(sha1sum $FILE)

if [[ ! $SUM1 == $SUM2 ]]; then
  echo "Different" #put your command here
fi
```

When executing:

```
nxr ~ touch filetest
nxr ~ bash sumtest.sh 1 filetest
-> Different
nxr ~ bash sumtest.sh 1 filetest
->
nxr ~ bash sumtest.sh 2 filetest
-> Different
```